# Stored Procedure doesn't work and I don't know why

Tags: mysql, linux, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have a problem, I don't found my error but this stored procedure doesn't work. In theory, when the OSbuild is too old, this SP will run another SP who make an alert.

My SP receive a uuid (varchar) and two timestamps (now I don't use them).

I have the table named "tb_build_requerido" with this info:

```
________________________________________
|build_requerido         |     so      |
|------------------------|-------------|
|3.12.50                 |    linux    |
|7200                    |    windows  |
|________________________|_____________|
```

In fact, if a PC has a previous Linux kernel version or previous Windows build version, it will make that my SP run another SP (acceir_generar_alerta_lista).

In my SP I made some selects in order to know if the PC has Windows or Linux (that data is in "System" table) and then to know which build/kernel version it has.

Here my SP code.

```
DROP PROCEDURE `acceir_so_necesario`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `acceir_so_necesario`(IN equipo_id Varchar(100), IN ts_actual BIGINT(20), IN ts_anterior BIGINT(20))

BEGIN
DECLARE v_equipo VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE v_build VARCHAR(100); 
DECLARE v_so VARCHAR(100); 
DECLARE v_build_requerido VARCHAR(100); 

DECLARE `eof` BOOL;

DECLARE so_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT system_uuid, system_build_number, so FROM ( (SELECT DISTINCT system_uuid, CONVERT( system_build_number, UNSIGNED INTEGER ) AS system_build_number, 'windows' AS so FROM `system` WHERE (  system_build_number REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}') )UNION ( SELECT DISTINCT system_uuid, INET_ATON( CONCAT( substring_index( system_build_number, '-', 1 ) , REPEAT( '.0', 3 - CHAR_LENGTH( substring_index( system_build_number, '-', 1 ) ) + CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE( substring_index( system_build_number, '-', 1 ) , '.', '' ) ) ) ) ) AS system_build_number, 'linux' AS so FROM `system` WHERE system_build_number NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}' ) )T1 WHERE system_uuid LIKE 'equipo_id' ;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET eof = TRUE; 
OPEN so_cursor;
`lp`: LOOP
    FETCH so_cursor INTO v_equipo, v_build, v_so; 
    IF `eof` IS TRUE THEN
        LEAVE `lp`;
    END IF;
    IF v_so = 'windows' THEN
        SET v_build_requerido = (SELECT CONVERT(build_requerido, UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS build_requerido FROM `tb_build_requerido` WHERE build_requerido_so = 'windows' ORDER BY  tb_build_requerido.build_requerido_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1);
        IF v_build < v_build_requerido THEN
            CALL acceir_generar_alerta_lista (equipo_id, 'actualizar sistema operativo windows', 'actualizar sistema operativo windows');
        END IF;
    END IF;
    IF v_so = 'linux' THEN
        SET v_build_requerido = (SELECT INET_ATON( CONCAT( build_requerido, REPEAT( '.0', 3 - CHAR_LENGTH(build_requerido) + CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(build_requerido, '.','')) ))) AS build_requerido FROM `tb_build_requerido` WHERE build_requerido_so = 'linux' ORDER BY  tb_build_requerido.build_requerido_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1);
        IF v_build < v_build_requerido THEN
            CALL acceir_generar_alerta_lista (equipo_id, 'actualizar sistema operativo linux', 'actualizar sistema operativo linux');
        END IF;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE so_cursor;
END//
```

The data I use was this INPUT PARAMETER equipo_id : 'IUA1000.WORKGROUP.Linux'

And, if I try the selects out of the SP it returns the following (correct) values.

Select --> so_cursor:

```
________________________________________________________________
|system_uuid             |    system_build_number   |  so      |
|------------------------|--------------------------|----------|
|IUA1000.WORKGROUP.Linux |    51183616              |  linux   |
|________________________|__________________________|__________|
```

Select --> v_build_requerido:

```
__________________
|build_requerido |
|----------------|
|51190880        |
|________________|
```

Anyone can tell me where is my error?? Thanks in advance... I'm using PHPmyAdmin MySQL, MariaDB, Ubuntu/Suse.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a very vague and practically useless description of the behavior you observe. What do you expect to happen, or not happen?  I'm not understanding why your query is comparing `system_uuid` to the literal string `'equipo_id'` in the WHERE clause.  It looks to me like you'd want to be referencing the procedure argument `equipo_id`, not a string literal. I'm not understanding how that SELECT can return the resultset shown. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @spencer7593, sorry for my poor explanation, but if I know what is it wrong, I don't be here... `system_uuid ` is a varchar in system table, so I tryed to compared with `'equipo_id'` which is also a varchar, so I don't understand what is it wrong... **The idea of my SP is** --> _not the minimum build/kernel version?_, **then**, _run another SP..._ **else**, _do nothing and be happy..._ I don't know if I'm using cursors and if statements in the correct way. If you don't understand anything, please ask me again... I really need help :( Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought my comment was pretty clear. This is the part of the query that I'm not understanding:

```
WHERE system_uuid LIKE 'equipo_id'
                       ^         ^
```

Specifically, the **single quotes** around `equipo_id`. Those single quotes means that MySQL sees that as a ***string literal***.  That is, MySQL sees it as a constant value. It is *not* a reference to a procedure variable.

So I don't understand how the query could return a value of value of `'IUA1000.WORKGROUP.Linux'` for the `system_uuid` column.

The only value of `system_uuid` column that would satisfy the predicate in that query is an exact match to the *literal string*.

To get that, we would either need

```
WHERE system_uuid LIKE 'IUA1000.WORKGROUP.Linux'
                       ^                       ^
```

Or, if we want to reference the value stored in a procedure variable, we'd need to omit the single quotes:

```
WHERE system_uuid LIKE equipo_id
```

Comment: AHHHHHH!!!! I LOVE YOU SO MUCH!!!! Now I understand what you said before... Sorry for not understand you, I never used variables in the past so I didn't know that I need to omit the single quotes. REALLY, THANKS A LOT!!!!